# Azure devops upload bugs with linked tests (id/ name)

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is it possible to import/ upload bugs along with linked tests (by id/ name) in Azure devops?

The microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops)  mention about importing work ites with parent - child relationship. I need to import bug and associate it with test case id/ name (direct link relationship).  E.g. In csv file I   can mention bug title in one column and associated test case id/ name in other. Then I should be able to upload csv file, and test case should be automatically linked to bug after upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have suggested a feature with MSFT

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/952141/import-upload-bugs-along-with-linked-tests-by-id-n.html.

Please vote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

As I know this feature is not supported yet. We can't import bug and associate it with test case id/ name (direct link relationship) from csv file.

When creating Query, no field in filter can match the direct linked work item. Also,  `Exporting to csv` option doesn't support this, see:

[image]

As an alternative way, I suggest you can post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) in our DC forum(user voice forum). If it get enough points, the team would consider it seriously. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Lance, will request a feature. Is it possible to link a test case to a bug through Azure Devops Rest API interface?

Comment: You can use rest api to update one workItem. And here's one sample about how to [add link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-link). Let me know if it helps or not :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have linked the bugs/tests with work Item , it can be exported as a CSV, you can read about more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops).

Comment: The microsoft docs mention about importing work ites with parent - child relationship. I need to import bug and associate it with test case id/ name (direct link relationship).  E.g. In csv file I   can mention bug title in one column and associated test case id/ name in other. Then I should be able to upload csv file, and test case should be automatically linked to bug.